# Windows 10 Technical Preview com Hyper-V

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Bom dia pessoal,

Eu tenho criado apps para Android usando o Android Studio mas pretendo usar Xamarin.
Como atualmente uso Win8.1 Single Language, o Hyper-V não está disponível recurso do Windows.
Sabem dizer se o Windows 10 possui o Hyper-V, pois se possuir eu atualizo e sucesso.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

A versão Preview disponível é a `Professional` (ultima que baixei) portanto o Hyper-V está disponível.

**Observações:**

1. `WIN10` Preview não é recomendável para produção;
2. Pode conter vários bugs, inclusive no `Hyper-V`;
3. Note que quando a versão `Preview` tem um tempo limitado de testes, após será necessário formatar sua máquina;
4. Salvo engano, quando atualizar sua versão do `WIN8` para `WIN10` ele manterá sua versão atual `Single Language` e provavelmente não terá suporte a `Hyper-V`;
5. Se estiver pensando apenas em desenvolver para Android `Hyper-V` não é fundamental, pode baixar o SDK e usar o emulador Android.